# ¿Cómo maquetar un slider mobile first sólo con HTML5 y CSS3?

Tags: html, css

Soy un novato intentando realizar en un proyecto de un book store un slider responsive que contenga tres imagenes (las tres son de 1200x495) y se adapte bien. He intentado buscar un montón de videos al respecto pero en todos las imagenes se ven rotas o no anda la transition o es un diseño que sólo se ve bien en desktop nada más o en una página vacía.

¿Alguno tiene algún consejo, maqueta o recurso que pudiera facilitarme para hacerlo?

Para dar un poco más de contexto, lo único que busco es que el slider cumpla la función de "banner" en mi home con imagenes de archivo que vayan cambiando constantemente de forma automática.

Desde ya, muchas gracias y perdón la molestia.

Comment: Te explico, yo como tengo bastante puntaje me aparece un botón que dice `cerrar`, yo lo presiono y me aparece una lista de motivos validos para cerrar una pregunta. Uno de ellos dice `La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías u otros recursos externos` y hay otro motivo que dice `Basada en opiniones` que es lo que es un concejo. Te recomiendo reformular tu pregunta, indicando claramente el resultado esperado y agregando el código de lo que has intentando hacer

Comment: Comentas que ya encontraste algunos que "funcionan" pero se ven rotas o solo se ven en desktop. Complementando lo que dice Yussef, pon ese código simplificado pero funcional. Usa un fiddle o la herramienta interna, y entonces se te podrá ayudar a arreglarlo.